# What does the syntax !function() { ... } mean?

Tags: javascript

I found this syntax in the simple, great, wonderful and powerful library [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com):

```
!function(factory) { ... }
```

What is the meaning of the not sign (`!`) before the `function` declaration?

UPDATE: The source code no longer contains this exact syntax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `!` operator behaves as normal, negating the expression. In this case it is used to force the function to be a function expression instead of a function statement. Since the `!` operator must be applied to an expression (it makes no sense to apply it to a statement, because statements don't have a value), the function will be interpreted as an expression.

This way it can be executed immediately.

```
function(){
    alert("foo");
}(); // error since this function is a statement, 
     // it doesn't return a function to execute

!function(){
    alert("foo");
}(); // This works, because we are executing the result of the expression
// We then negate the result. It is equivalent to:

!(function(){
    alert("foo");
}());

// A more popular way to achieve the same result is:
(function(){
    alert("foo");
})();
```

Comment: If the function returns `true`, will it change it to `false`?

Comment: @Derek Yes, any truthy value returned from the function will be negated to false and vice-versa. However, in the code the OP referenced the returned value is not used so the purpose of the `!` is only to allow the function to be immediately invoked.

Comment: So is `!!function(){}` better if the returned value is important?

Comment: If the function returns something then it would usually have a name an would be declared to be used somewhere else. You could use operators such as `+`,`-`,`~` to force it to be a function expression.

Comment: @Derek I usually prefer the fourth way I wrote, the ending parenthesis could also be changed from `)()` to `())` for the same effect. Using the parenthesis you do nothing to the returned value, whereas using `!!` will convert the returned value to a boolean. So if the function returns an object you'd end up with the value `true` instead of the object the function returned if you use `!!`, but with just parenthesis you'll get the object.

Comment: @ascii-lime - I use `(...)()` all the time too, and this is the first time I see `!...()` and I am curious if this is better 'cause this is one character shorter o.O

Comment: @Derek As elclanrs wrote, you can use any operator that requires an expression as an operand. You could put any unary operator like `void`, `~`, `+`, `-`, `!`. Or you could use a binary operator with a dummy value: `0,func...`, `0 + func...`.

Comment: @Derek If you want to make sure that your Javascript is the least number of bytes you can, it may be worth it to use one of the single character operators, and in other situations it may be worth it to use the operator that does what you want (if you actually want to negate or compliment the return value for example).